# What does c = c & (1 << bit) do?

Tags: java, int

Given c is an int, I don't understand what the statement `c = c & (1 << bit)` does. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about the statement?

Comment: @Oded I think that is his question.

Comment: @JonH - I was hoping he would expand on which part of the statement or if the statement as a whole.

Comment: It could also be written as `c &= (1 << bit);`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It masks out everything but the `bit`-th bit of `c`.

e.g. if `c = 27` and `bit = 3`:

```
         c = 27 = 00011011 (binary)
(1 << bit) =  8 = 00001000
    result =      00001000 = 8
```

and when `bit = 2`:

```
         c = 27 = 00011011 (binary)
(1 << bit) =  4 = 00000100
    result =      00000000 = 0
```

Note that the result will either be equal to `(1 << bit)` (a power of 2) or `0`.

Comment: +1 for what they said ;)

I think I understand.. Is this assumption correct? :

if bit = 7, then the result, for any given c is either 64 or 0 ?

Comment: @KeesKoenen: `(1 << 7)` is 128, so the result is always 128 or 0.

Answer (score 6):

It sets all bits in `c` to zero, except the bit at position `bit` counting from the right. That particular bit is left unchanged. Essentially, this is one way of checking whether the bit at position `bit` is set (`c > 0`) or not (`c == 0`)

Comment: you could add that it leaves the bit at position bit unchanged (i.e., it does not set it to 1 unconditionally)